# Handling Google Transliteration in React-native

Tags: react-native, google-translate

Is there any difference between Google Transliterate and Google Translate API?
- I'm using Google Cloud Translation API in my React-native Project.Now , everything works fine .For example ,if type "Hello" then it will gave me a translated result(say - "नमस्ते") in target language (Hindi). But now, my requirement is not for translation.I want if type "Hello" in English, then it gave me a result as "हेलो " in Hindi.This is i want to achieve ,Please suggest me some tips!

Note: In web, its working cool like if i type "Hello" then they gave me "हेलो" in Hindi.But in my react-native android/Ios project it doesn't provide me my expected result its always translate the input text.

Answer (score 0):

So far of my knowledge the transliteration API of Google has been documented to be [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started).

However outside of the cloud services there seems to be a new tool called [Google input Tools](https://www.google.com/inputtools/try/) in which they apparently test the transliteration. Probably they'll come with a cloud services version in the future.

Comment: so how can i use Google-Input Tools in android. I'm aware of using Google Translate But how can i do this for Google Input